Move Spreadsheet from My Drive to Shared Drive
I have a script that creates a new spreadsheet and copies two tabs from the current sheet to the new sheet. I would prefer if the new sheet were saved in a shared drive folder instead of my My Drive. Below is the current iteration I'm working on. The commented out lines are the ones that don't work.
function SaveNewFinancials() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Inputs'), true);  
  var filename = spreadsheet.getRange("B15").getValue();
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(filename);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Balance Sheet'), true);  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Balance Sheet");
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Profit and Loss'), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Profit and Loss");
  newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));
  //var folderID = "xxxxxxx3nTzzyS-I1pWzsejHDCh5";
  //var sharedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  //var sharedDriveID = "xxxxxxxxenHXUk9PVA";
  //var resource = {title: filename, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, parents: [{driveid: sharedDriveID, id: sharedFolder}]};
  //Drive.Files.copy(resource, newSpreadsheet,{supportsAllDrives: true});

I've enabled the advanced drive service, but I still get errors when attempting to find the folder in the shared drive.
I've tried using moveTo and copyTo, but I learned that DriveApp doesn't play well with shared drives. I also don't think I need the drive ID, but I saw it in a few other answers here so I added it in my latest attempt. Thanks in advance for any help!

try like this:
function SaveNewFinancials() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  // Set the active sheet to 'Inputs' and get the filename from cell B15
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Inputs'), true);  
  var filename = spreadsheet.getRange("B15").getValue();
  
  // Create a new spreadsheet with the obtained filename
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(filename);
  
  // Copy the 'Balance Sheet' sheet to the new spreadsheet and rename it
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Balance Sheet'), true);  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Balance Sheet");
  
  // Copy the 'Profit and Loss' sheet to the new spreadsheet and rename it
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Profit and Loss'), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Profit and Loss");
  
  // Delete the default 'Sheet1' from the new spreadsheet
  newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));

  // The shared folder ID where the new spreadsheet will be moved
  var folderID = "xxxxxxx3nTzzyS-I1pWzsejHDCh5"; // Replace with your shared folder ID
  var fileID = newSpreadsheet.getId();

  // Use the Drive API to move the file to the shared folder
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  folder.addFile(file);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
}


As another approach, how about the following modifications?
About but I still get errors when attempting to find the folder in the shared drive., unfortunately, from your question, I cannot confirm your actual error message. But, from your showing script and the current specification at the script editor, you might have tested your showing script by enabling Drive API v3. In the current stage, when Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google services, version 3 is automatically set as the default version. If it's so, an error occurs because resource of your showing script is for Drive API v2. If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample scripts?
Use Drive API
Before you test this, please enable Drive API v3 at Advanced Google services. And please set your destination folder ID to destinationFolderId.
/**
 * ### Description
 * Check whether Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google services, and return it as true or false and the version.
 * ref: https://medium.com/google-cloud/checking-api-enabled-with-advanced-google-services-using-google-apps-script-572bcdeb39a8
 *
 * @param {String} apiName API name you want to check.
 * @returns {Object} Object including "api" and "version" properties.
 */
function isAPIAtAdvancedGoogleServices_(apiName) {
  if (!apiName || apiName == "" || typeof apiName != "string") {
    throw new Error("Please set a valid API name.");
  } else if (!/^[A-Z]+$/g.test(apiName[0])) {
    const [t, ...b] = apiName;
    apiName = [t.toUpperCase(), ...b].join("");
  }
  const obj = { apiName, api: "disable" };
  if (typeof this[apiName] !== "undefined") {
    obj.api = "enable";
    obj.version = this[apiName].getVersion();
  }
  return obj;
}

function SaveNewFinancials() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Inputs'), true);  
  var filename = spreadsheet.getRange("B15").getValue();
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(filename);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Balance Sheet'), true);  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Balance Sheet");
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Profit and Loss'), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Profit and Loss");
  newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));


  // I modified the below script.
  const destinationFolderId = "###"; // Please set your destination folder ID (in shared drive).
  const sourceFileId = newSpreadsheet.getId();
  const check = isAPIAtAdvancedGoogleServices_("Drive");
  if (check.api == "enable" && check.version == "v3") {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // I'm not sure whether this line is required.
    Drive.Files.update({}, sourceFileId, null, { addParents: destinationFolderId, enforceSingleParent: true, supportsAllDrives: true });
  } else {
    console.warn("Please enable Drive API v3 at Advanced Google services.");
  }
}

Use Drive service (DriveApp)
About I've tried using moveTo and copyTo, but I learned that DriveApp doesn't play well with shared drives., when I tested the following script for moving the Spreadsheet for the shared drive, I confirmed that the Spreadsheet could be moved from my drive to the shared drive. So, please test the following script.
Please set your destination folder ID to destinationFolderId.
function SaveNewFinancials() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Inputs'), true);  
  var filename = spreadsheet.getRange("B15").getValue();
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(filename);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Balance Sheet'), true);  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Balance Sheet");
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Profit and Loss'), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Profit and Loss");
  newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));


  // I modified the below script.
  const destinationFolderId = "###"; // Please set your destination folder ID (in shared drive).
  const sourceFileId = newSpreadsheet.getId();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // I'm not sure whether this line is required.
  DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId).moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId));
}

Note:

In the current stage, the methods "addFile(child)", "addFolder(child)", "removeFile(child)", and "removeFolder(child)" are deplicated while those can be still used. Ref.

References:

Method: files.update of Drive API v3
moveTo(destination) of Class File

